# Chain two barriers in ConstraintLayout

Tags: android, xml, android-constraintlayout, constraint-layout-chains, constraintlayout-barrier

I'm going to achieve this goal using `ConstraintLayout`:
[image]

The length of each TextView is not fixed and may change and the TextViews should be in the middle of their columns. I guessed that barriers and guidelines could help me if I chain **barrier_left** and **barrier_right** using `app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread_inside"`, so I checked it out:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Barrier
        android:id="@+id/barrier_left"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        app:barrierDirection="left"
        app:constraint_referenced_ids="tv_left_1,tv_left_2,tv_left_3"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/barrier_right"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread_inside"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_left_1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:text="Left 1 AA"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_left_2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:text="Left 2 AAA"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/tv_left_1"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/tv_left_1"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_left_1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_left_3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:text="Left 3 AAAA"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/tv_left_2"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/tv_left_2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_left_2" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.5" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_middle_1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:text="Middle 1 AA"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/guideline"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_middle_2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:text="Middle 2 AAAAAA"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/guideline"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tv_middle_1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_middle_3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:text="Middle 3 AAAA"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/guideline"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_middle_2" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_right_1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:text="Right 1 AAAAAAAAA"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/barrier_right"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_right_2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:text="Right 2 AAAA"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_right_1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_right_3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:text="Right 3 A"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/tv_right_2"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/tv_right_2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_right_2" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Barrier
        android:id="@+id/barrier_right"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        app:barrierDirection="right"
        app:constraint_referenced_ids="tv_right_1,tv_right_2,tv_right_3"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/barrier_left" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

but it didn't work at all! **It is the result:**

[image]

**And this is my Design Surface:**

[image]

I need to keep all Views on the screen (none of them should go out) and each View should place in the center of its column. I need to give some space from the Middle column to the left or right column if left or right ones are longer and need space.
How can I arrange the Views like the one shown in the first image?

Answer (score 0):

I checked your code and maybe my version will be good for you. try like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <android.support.constraint.Barrier
        android:id="@+id/barrier_left"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        app:barrierDirection="right"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread_inside"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_left_1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:text="Left 1 AA"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/tv_left_2"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/tv_left_2"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_left_2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:text="Left 2 AAA"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/tv_left_3"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/tv_left_3"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_left_1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_left_3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:text="Left 3 AAAA"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/barrier_left"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tv_left_2"/>

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.5" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_middle_1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:text="Middle 1 AA"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/guideline"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_middle_2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:text="Middle 2 AAAAAA"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/guideline"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tv_middle_1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_middle_3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:text="Middle 3 AAAA"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/guideline"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_middle_2" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_right_1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:text="Right 1 AAAAAAAAA"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/barrier_right"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_right_2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:text="Right 2 AAAA"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/tv_right_1"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/tv_right_1"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_right_1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_right_3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:text="Right 3 A"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/tv_right_2"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/tv_right_2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_right_2" />

    <android.support.constraint.Barrier
        android:id="@+id/barrier_right"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        app:barrierDirection="left"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: it doesn't work well if you change `tv_left_1` text to `"Left 1 AAAAAAAA"`

Comment: Do you have a better idea?

Comment: but witch result you expect in this case?

Comment: all texts will be centred to biggest?

Comment: Yes, Exactly. all text should be centered to the biggest and none of them should go out of the screen

Comment: You need to make it runtime... check the text length and make changes to constraint. the pattern as in my example the longest will be connected to barrier and other texts will be startToStart & endToEnd to longest...

Comment: Oh, no! Do you really think there is no easier way?

Answer (score 0):

Didn't get your requirement clearly. But you can try this one

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Barrier
        android:id="@+id/barrier_left"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        app:barrierDirection="right"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread_inside"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline_left"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.33" />

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline_right"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.66" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_left_1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:text="Left 1 AAAAAAAA"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/barrier_left"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline_left"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_left_2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:text="Left 2 AAA"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/barrier_left"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline_left"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_left_1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_left_3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:text="Left 3 AAAA"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/barrier_left"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline_left"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tv_left_2"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_middle_1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:text="Middle 1 AA"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline_right"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/guideline_left"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_middle_2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:text="Middle 2 AAAAAA"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline_right"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/guideline_left"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tv_middle_1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_middle_3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:text="Middle 3 AAAA"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline_right"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/guideline_left"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_middle_2" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_right_1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:text="Right 1 AAAAAAAAA"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/barrier_right"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/guideline_right"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_right_2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:text="Right 2 AAAA"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/barrier_right"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/guideline_right"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_right_1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_right_3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:text="Right 3 A"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/barrier_right"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/guideline_right"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_right_2" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Barrier
        android:id="@+id/barrier_right"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        app:barrierDirection="left"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: I need to keep all Views in the screen (none of them should go out) and each View should in the center of its column. your answer is like a LinearLayout that has 3 other layouts init with the same weight. I need to give some space from the Middle column to the left column if left ones are longer and need space. now it doesn't happen in your answer.